# Push Notifications to view

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

In my web application, I want to show notifications to the users once it triggers there is a new record. So I have followed a few tutorials and using SignalR I have completed the notification collecting process.

I want to show the notifications results from the script to the view. I'm struggling to assign them to the view.?

This is the script I wrote in the Layout

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/signalr/Hubs/"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
   debugger
   // Proxy created on the fly
   var hub = $.connection.notifications
   // Declare a function on the hub hub so the server can invoke it
   hub.client.displayNoti = function () {
   debugger
   getData();
   };
  // Start the connection
   $.connection.hub.start();
   getData();

   function getData() {
    var divNotificaion = $('#divNotificaion');
     $.ajax({
      url: '/Notification/GetNotification',
      type: 'GET',
      datatype: 'json',
      success: function (data) {
      debugger
      data = $.parseJSON(data);
      if (data.length > 0) {
      divNotificaion.empty();
      //// set Count
      $('#ntCnt').text(data.length);

      ///Make notification html
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      var notification = '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">' +'<a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>'+ data[i].Message +'</div>'
      Notificationsdiv.append(notification);
     }

     }
    }, error: function (r, e, w) {
   }
  });
 }
})
</script>
```

In this view, this is the area I want to show notifications.

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
 <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
   <i class="far fa-bell"></i>
      <span class="badge badge-warning navbar-badge">15</span> @*Here I want to show the Count*@
       </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-lg dropdown-menu-right">

           @*Here I want to show the notification message*@
           <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
 
       </div>
</li>
```

So I want to know from the script how can I pass the result to this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could split into two js function returning count and message and then embed those functions names as you would normally insert js into html , if that is what you are asking